# Google BigQuery - Moderate size join, Backend Error

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to do an inner join between one table with 40,514 rows (less than 1 Mb table) and a table with 4,359,682 rows (~450MB).

In the past I have been successful in performing these kind of joins, and I beleive I'm adhering to the 10MB small join size limit, but I get a Backend error when I try and do this. In the past I would halve the smaller table and do two joins and aggregate them, but in this case, that isn't an option.

I would expect a more informative error message, does anyone know what kind of problem is causing this error?

My projectid is 340400313423

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you've hit 5 errors in queries using JOIN in the past week:

```
QUERY_ERROR    Encountered "" at line 1, column 63. Was expecting one of:
INVALID_VALUE  Unknown field: Channel
QUERY_ERROR    BAD_QUERY (YT_Account appears in GROUP BY, but it is not a named column in SELECT)
INVALID_VALUE  Table raw has no field c.Policy
INVALID_VALUE  Unknown field: Policy
```

None of these are related to the size of the JOIN you're doing. And you should get a more informative error if you look at the rest of the response.

Comment: Thanks Jordan, I'm using the web interface and "Backend Error" is the only error message I see. Is there a way I can see the kind of error message that you posted on the web interface?

Comment: Can you send the query that you are running that hit the backend error? If it is sensitive, you can e-mail it to me at my last name at google.com.